# How should I ARIA-decorate my control?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have a control that's almost exactly the same as one at this site: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen. Specifically, the "Multiple Select" control under the "Selected and Disabled Support" section.

I can't work out what ARIA roles to use with it. It's kind of a listbox in its function, but you can't move up and down the list, using space to select things. It's also not a combobox because you can't type in arbitrary new values (although that might come later).

Would welcome some help with this, as I'm keen to make it as accessible as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look would be:

- the main box  would need to be a `listbox`
- the elements within that need to be `option`
- `aria-haspopup="true"` needs to be added when the drop down appears I *think*.
- `aria-multiselecta1ble="true"` needs to be set

Comment: Sorry is "the main box" the input box or the dropdown? Could the dropdown be a "menu"? It all seems very subjective, this ARIA stuff. How do you know what's right?

Comment: "main box" yes the input. To be honest I didn't study the code much to see how it is put together. No the drop down should not be a `menu`. `"A menu is often a list of common actions or functions that the user can invoke. The menu role is appropriate when a list of menu items is presented in a manner similar to a menu on a desktop application."` [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#menu)

Comment: It's just that on the [MDN listbox page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_listbox_role), under the "Possible effects on user agents and assistive technology" section, they talk about a combo box owning a listbox as a menu ...

Comment: That is basically saying "Ok web browser, when you see `role='listbox'`, you can allow it to have the same [native] functionality as a menu, i.e. the file menu." If you look under it, there is a note that says it is only one opinion, not how it actually works. If you look at the code example, it mimics what I suggested (note i only reviewed the W3C ARIA Spec for my answer, and I quoted the source for my comment).